# getting every n'th row in eigen MatrixXf

Tags: c++, eigen

I would like to do simple stuff - extract every second row in a matrix of shape [4,5] to get two output matrices of shapes [2,5]. My matrix is:

```
Eigen::MatrixXf m(4,5);
m << 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20;
```

when I print I get the expected:

```
 1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
```

Now how to obtain the expected outputs: ?

```
// expected mOut1:
 1  2  3  4  5
11 12 13 14 15
// and expected mOut2:
 6  7  8  9 10
16 17 18 19 20
```

So far I tried with `Eigen::Map` and strides, but I have no idea how do those strides work.
I made a function:

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXf, 0, Eigen::Stride<Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>> myMatrixSlice(const float* data, unsigned dim1, unsigned dim2, int stride1, int stride2) {
   using Stride = Eigen::Stride<Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>;
   return Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXf, 0, Stride>{
       const_cast<float*>(data), dim1, dim2, Stride{stride1, stride2}};
}
```

and I want to call it like this:

```
auto mOut1 = myMatrixSlice(m.data(), 2, 5, ?, ?);
auto mOut2 = myMatrixSlice(m.data(), 2, 5, ?, ?); // remember to start with row=1
```

but I guess I need some help on this.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html

Comment: nice but I have Eigen in version 3.3.9